# target.event by JQuery executed multiple times

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This is my current code:

```
function tableClick(event){
    $('#table').click(function(event){
        alert(event.target.id);     
    });
}

<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td id="td1" onclick="tableClick(this)">
            1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="td2" onclick="tableClick(this)">
            2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I don't understand is why it pops up the alert window one more time than last. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Each time you click, you call this function.

```
function tableClick(event){
    $('#table').click(function(event){
        alert(event.target.id);     
    });
}
```

This part:

```
$('#table').click(function(event){
```

attaches a click handler to the table. **Every time you click** you attach a new click handler to the table.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are attaching click handler on every click -

You can do this -

```
function tableClick(this){
     alert(this.id);     
}
```

Comment: Thank. But it seems this doesn't work. So I keep it as tableClick(event) {alert(event.id);} and it workds